# Using VMServer 2.0 is it possible to copy and paste images between host and guest

Tags: vmware-server, clipboard

I've tried to do this but can't get it to work. 
Works fine with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the host<->guest clipboard integration is text only in my experience.

To transfer images and other data you'll need to drop the data to a file and transfer that by network fileshare, or by connecting to the VM via something like RDC or VNC and using the remote connection protocol's file transfer support.

Comment: I thought so, very irritating as they are explicitly on separate networks. I'm currently using the scripting as you suggest.

Capturing a screenshot becomes annoying...